# Apex Grid Not Recognised by QTP 11.0

Tags: qtp

I want to automate a `VB` windows application with a Grid View in it. when i record the object using `QTP 11.0` its recorded as a `winObject "TG50.ApexGrid32.20"`
Can anyone please let me know how to get control over this object.
I want to select a row in that grid.

I tried using mentioned line of code, but it didn't worked:

```
VbWindow("MainForm_2").WinObject("TG50.ApexGrid32.20").Click
VbWindow("MainForm_2").WinObject("TG50.ApexGrid32.20").Click  micRightBtn
```

Also let me know is there any add in i need to install for this?
I am currently using only `VB` addin of `QTP`.

Also i tried using `DP`, but that too failed
Lines written by me are mentioned below:

```
Set gridobj = Description.Create
gridobj("micclass").value = VbWindow("MainForm_2").WinObject("TG50.ApexGrid32.20")
Set gridcoll = VbWindow("MainForm_2").WinObject("TG50.ApexGrid32.20").ChildObjects(gridobj)
gridcoll(0).click
gridcoll(0).click micRightBtn
```

Answer (score 0):

Do Make sure that you open application after you have opened QTP as if application is opened prior to QTP then QTP would fail to recognize the objects.

Make sure that you have installed Active X and VB addins. If your application is using VB.NET technology then you need to add .NET Add in.

Thanks